# SQL INSERT INTO works without any errors but does not show any data? (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I've been teaching myself SQL for an upcoming school project.

Now, my problem is rather weird, The INSERT INTO command works fine, so do the values and parameters.

However, when i open my table nothing shows up, it either creates an empty row or simply inserts "0".

The connection string is working and the table name is correct, as well as the database itself.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RegistrationForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string username,password,firstName,lastName,birthDate,phoneNumber,email;

        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox6.Clear();
            textBox7.Clear();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\LOCALDBDEMO;Initial Catalog=ATC_DATA;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT TEST (UserName) VALUES (@UserName)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", textBox1.Text);



            username = textBox1.Text;
            password = textBox2.Text;
            firstName = textBox3.Text;
            lastName = textBox4.Text;
            phoneNumber = textBox6.Text;
            email = textBox7.Text;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the actual picture of the rows: 
[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHewR.png)

**NOTE: I am trying to create a sort of Registration form in Windows Forms (C#).**

Comment: Post the query and code. There's no such thing as an empty row - it's still a row, with nulls or empty strings, or 0s.

Comment: Without having look on your code how could we assume? Include your code snippet on your question.

Comment: Since you *do* get a row, the problem most likely is the way you construct the query (if you use string concatenation) or the way you pass the parameter values. Are you using the wrong Add overload to create parameters perhaps?

Comment: did you commit?

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon the OP said nothing about starting a transaction. A row did appear, but had default values

Comment: If you try to pass a name and integer value with `Add(someName,1)` you'll end up calling [Add(string,SqlDbType)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_), not the *obsolete* [Add(string,Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Object_) method.

Comment: Enums are essentially labeled integers so `Add(string,SqlDbType)` is a better match than `Add(string,Object)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot '@' in adding value...try

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", textBox1.Text);
```